# How to get internal content of jsf component?

Tags: java, jsf, custom-component

I have a component's library and this library has Chart component. Chart is actually a jpg image.

I need to access this image. I need some basic tips where to search that image, maybe with examples based on some wellknown libraries like Tomahawk.

Comment: Which component library? Which component/tag?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using something like jQuery to help you acess the html page's dom structure after the page is rendered via javascript. Getting the image will be as simple as looking up a component by Id

Comment: I'm thinking about something similar too. But I still hope to find server-side solution.

Comment: the chart images are probably generated on the fly and streamed back to the browser instantaneously. In this case, they wont really be stored anywhere on the server unless there is some sort of caching involved.